# Postfix sends to wrong address

Tags: networking, server, cron, email, postfix

I have a cron job that sends a report out once a day. The server is configured with postfix and the mailutils, and mailutils-common packages. On 20.04, I was able to send emails out no issue like this:

```
echo '' | sudo mail -s 'Config Drift' my@email.com  --attach=/home/user/report.csv
```

And that works fine using Gmail SMTP with HELO authentication (external IP address is set under /etc/mailname)

I built a new server on 22.04, and things behave differently with the exact same config. I never get the emails, and in my `/var/log/mail.log`, I see that the TO address is the root user on the server. On 20.04, the email was sent to `my@email.com`

Is there something that changed in 22.04 that would cause this behavior?